# aniamtionLoop not working in Flexslider

Tags: flexslider

I have a slider of 4 slides that should have an infinite loop, so when you reach the last one it continues to slide 1, at the moment it slides back all the way to the first, I thought animationLoop: true would do this but it doesn't:

```
var children_slides = $('.flexslider_children').flexslider({
  slideshow: false, // Remove the animations
  controlNav : false, // Remove the controls
   animation: "fade",
   directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
    animationSpeed: 1000

}); 

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    slideshow: false, // Remove the animations
  pauseOnHover : true,
   animation: "slide",
    itemWidth: 244,
     animationLoop:true,
  animationSpeed: 1000,
  slideshowSpeed: 5000,
  initDelay: 3000,
  manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li a",
  // Call the update_children_slides which itterates through all children slides 
  'before' : function(slider){ // Hijack the flexslider
    update_children_slides(slider.animatingTo);
  }   
});
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you remove string

> itemWidth: 244,

animationLoop will be work

Comment: That's really bizarre! Why does it work that way?  I'm trying to set one up with a minItems value of 2 and I want it when scrolling left to keep scrolling left and just bring item one back around but instead it does this hearkyjerky rewind to pull item one back to it's starting position...